# How nested loops are working in c#?

Tags: c#

Desired output:

> ```
>                         1
>                        121
>                       12321
>                      1234321
>                     123454321
> ```

Code:

```
for (r = 1; num >= r; r++)
{
    for (sp = num - r; sp >= 1; sp--)
        Console.Write(" ");
    for (c = 1; c <= r; c++)
        Console.Write(c);
    for (x = r - 1; x >= 1; x--)
        Console.Write(x);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

I'm trying this in c# I got the code in net. But I need to how it works exactly. Please some one explain how nested loops are works with Clear Explanation. Any help must be appreciated.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? The algorithm? The `for` statements in C#?

Comment: Define what you mean by "how it works exactly"?

Comment: Loops iterate over the code contained inside its block, What is unclear?

Comment: Thanks for will to help me. I didn't understand the above code..And also the structure of nested for loop.

Comment: @ patrick Holfman. Yes, I didn't understand the algorithm.

Comment: just like non nested for loops, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

Comment: Try to get comfortable with your debugger. That will help you more than the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. It is gud answer. Now I got the idea behind it through debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop iterates over the lines to print. The first inner loop prints the desired number of spaces in order to have the non-whitespace characters appear center aligned. The second inner loop prints the left half of the row, and finally the third inner loop prints the right half of the row.